# Module 'apple_sign_in' not found on Xcode but app build on Android Studio

Tags: xcode, flutter, cocoapods

When I try to build app on Xcode I get this error:
/Users/user/folder/appName/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:10:9: Module 'apple_sign_in' not found.
But if I use Android Studio the app builds fine.
So far I removed the podfile, podfile.lock, then cleaned up the build folder and then tried again, but nothing changed, the error persists.
Also uncommented the platform :ios, line and set it to different versions, the last I've tried is 13.0
Can anyone help me with this, please?

Answer (score 1):

try uncommenting  `# platform :ios, '9.0'` in podfile and add `use_frameworks!` line to the podfile.